# You do not have permission to access this page, please refer to your system administrator

Tags: opencart

I am an administrator, and I have installed an extension of News Letter from:

http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=12825

When I attempt to use this, it returns the error below:

> error:  You do not have permission to access this page, please refer to your system administrator.

Comment: Please Help me I'm total new for opencart

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Login to admin, go to `System > User Group`.
2. Edit your admin usergroup (probably `Top Administrator` group).
3. Add permission to your new extension modules (both `Access Permission` and `Modify Permission`).

That's all.

Have a nice day :) !!

Comment: Each section says "You do not have permission to access this page, please refer to your system administrator.". Cannot access any of the section, even logout is not working. Please advise

Comment: @ParmendraSingh Do you have access to 'System > User Group' page in admin panel ?

Comment: No, cannot access any section, in each section it says above message.

Comment: Is it a fresh opencart installation? Did you make any change in 'System > User Group' page earlier?

Comment: No I didn't change anything... it is an existing opencart.. I just setup it on my localhost from server. front end is working perfectly.

Comment: This is not the best solution, but If you have database access, use it and change the permission editing the database directly.

Comment: @Julianesten so whenever we need to change the permission, we should access the database and change it directly, right? you should also report opencart to remove this feature and tell them to make the users update the database everytime ;) !

Comment: @SankarV no way, I mean, is only when the top user administrator does not have any permission. Therefore is impossible do it via the System interface.

Comment: @Julianesten - by default, the top administrator do have permission to change the `User Group` permission. We need to change it via database only if the admin user accidentally revoke his/her own permission to update the `User Group` permission page. Also kindly note that in your first comment you just said : `This is not the best solution, but If you have database access, use it and change the permission editing the database directly.` The questioner already got it fixed with my solution.