# add custom shipping method to opencart

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I want to add custom shipping method to my store.
I tried to search for it in Google and found this articles

1. [Create a Custom Shipping Method in OpenCart: Part One](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-shipping-method-in-opencart-part-one--cms-25076)
2. [Create a Custom Shipping Method in OpenCart: Part Two](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-shipping-method-in-opencart-part-two--cms-25102)

it installed and works but when I want to edit it like add " Cost " and enable it I got:

```
Permission Denied! 

You do not have permission to access this page, please refer to your system administrator.
```

i tried this solution but doesnt work :
[You do not have permission to access this page, please refer to your system administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21235293/you-do-not-have-permission-to-access-this-page-please-refer-to-your-system-admi)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [You do not have permission to access this page, please refer to your system administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21235293/you-do-not-have-permission-to-access-this-page-please-refer-to-your-system-admi)

Comment: @HarnishDesign tried this and not resolved my issue :)